# How do I programmatically find out if polymer is not working?

Tags: web, browser, polymer

We are using `polymer` in our web app. The problem we are facing is, although we know that in older browsers (`Chrome 35` and before, `FF 28` and before etc.) `polymer is not supported`, is there a way that we can find out programmatically if any os / browser combination is not supporting polymer.

Though we are serving different websites for different browser version depending on their support of polymer, we are still getting user feedback that the site is not loading. The user sees a blank white page if polymer don't load.

Comment: post your relevant code...

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem comes down to whether the browser supports webcomponents/the polyfill.

[Issue #26](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/26) on webcomponentsjs talks about this. They do note that this technique does not work 100% of the time. The advantage of this approach is that it can be run immediately after the polyfill is loaded.

```
var webComponentsSupported = (
   'registerElement' in document &&
   'import' in document.createElement('link') &&
   'content' in document.createElement('template'));
```

However, an easier and more foolproof approach would be to attempt to create a custom element and check back later to see if the browser interpreted it as a custom element. For example:

```
var isRegistered = function(name) {
    return document.createElement(name).constructor !== HTMLElement;
}
```

If the browser understands custom element the constructor will no longer be HTMLElement. If you determine that your browser is not loading custom elements then you could use google analytics to send an event with details on the browser information etc.